# Decrypting Windows Password in terraform

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to set up a Terraform script to deploy a windows server. When running terraform apply I get an error message referencing below

```
Error: Invalid reference

  on main.tf line 44, in resource "aws_instance" "server":
  44:       password = "${rsadecrypt(aws_instance.server[0].password_data, file(KEY_PATH))}"

A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute
access, specifying the resource name.
```

AFAIK the resource is "aws_instance", the name is "server[0]" while the attribute is the "password_data". I know I'm missing something but don't know what. any assistance would be appreciated.

The full resource module is below in case there is something I'm missing contained in there.
Thanks

```
resource "aws_instance" "server" {
  ami                      = var.AMIS[var.AWS_REGION]
  instance_type            = var.AWS_INSTANCE
  vpc_security_group_ids  = [module.networking.security_group_id_out]
  subnet_id               = module.networking.subnet_id_out

  ## Use this count key to determine how many servers you want to create.
  count                   = 1
  key_name                = var.KEY_NAME
  tags = {
    # Name                  = "Server-Cloud"
    Name = "Server-${count.index}"
  }

  root_block_device {
    volume_size           = var.VOLUME_SIZE
    volume_type           = var.VOLUME_TYPE
    delete_on_termination = true
  }

  get_password_data = true

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    connection {
      host = coalesce(self.public_ip, self.private_ip)
      type = "winrm"

      ## Need to provide your own .pem key that can be created in AWS or on your machine for each provisioned EC2.
      password = ${rsadecrypt(aws_instance.server[0].password_data, file(KEY_PATH))}
    }
    inline = [
      "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\installserver.ps1 -Schedule",
    ]
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${self.public_ip} >> ../public_ips.txt"
  }
}
```

Comment: Think you just need `rsadecrypt(self.password_data, file(KEY_PATH))` assuming `KEY_PATH` is an actual path that you've removed from here or is replaced with something like `pathexpand("~/.ssh/id_rsa")`

Comment: I have the key path in a terraform.tfvars file  ```KEY_PATH = "C:\\Users\\paulj\\OneDrive\\Documents\\_Education Courses\\Training\\AWS\\keys"``` (I'm testing the terraform plan locally). I have attempted to use the self.password option but i get the same error.

Comment: `KEY_PATH` is not a valid variable reference. You would need `var.KEY_PATH` if you have defined the variable as `variable "KEY_PATH {}`

Comment: Thanks @ydaetskcoR it looks like the issue was the lack of the "var" portion of the variable name. adding that to the KEY_PATH gets past the issue. Thanks

Comment: I'm surprised that you can refer to the resource inside its own provisioner. That would normally error which is why the `self` keyword is available to provisioners but I haven't tested if that's still the case since Terraform 0.12.

Comment: based on that would it be best practice to change the provider details (what i thought was the original problem) to be self?

Answer (score 1):

Use `password = "${rsadecrypt(self.password_data, file("/root/.ssh/id_rsa"))}"`
without  `user = "admin"` as below :

```
resource "aws_instance" "windows_server" {

   get_password_data      =   "true"
   connection {
     host     = "${self.public_ip}"
     type     = "winrm"
     https    = false
     password = "${rsadecrypt(self.password_data, file("/root/.ssh/id_rsa"))}"
     agent    = false
     insecure = "true"
   }
}
```